# SVG.js move group containing symbol use element

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, svg.js

I'm using the SVG.js library in my project and I'm trying to move a group containing some `rect`, `text` and one `use`  element in x direction:

```js
// create symbol, symbol can be anything
const symbol = svg.symbol().circle(10)  

//create group with elements
const group = svg.group();
const rect = group.rect();
const text = group.plain('some text');
const symbolUse = svg.use(symbol);
group.add(symbolUse);

//some time later...move group to new x coordinate (can be anything)
group.x(newX)
```

Now it works completely fine with all the text and rect elements. They move just the way I want them to in x direction. But the use element somehow moves in x AND y direction, which it definetly should not do.

[image: SVG Elements structure]

[image: Use element moving wrong]

Now is this a bug from the SVG.js library or am I missing something regarding the use element?

Comment: Please replace the picture of code with a text-based [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `transform()` function.

See: https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/manipulating/#transforming

```js
var svg = SVG().addTo('body').size(300, 300)

const symbol = svg.symbol().circle(10)  

//create group with elements
const group = svg.group();
const rect = group.rect();
const text = group.plain('some text');
const symbolUse = svg.use(symbol);
group.add(symbolUse);

// Move the whole group right by 150 units
group.transform({translateX: 150});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The x function should work just fine. Maybe this is really a bug